# c# != operator not functioning correctly

Tags: c#, validation, operators

I don't know if it is just me being thick but I have a bit of validation code to check for a yes or no answer.

I can't seem to get it to work I have used the code in other places in my program and it works but I can't spot the error if there is one. The code runs through the while anyway no mater what the input character is.

```
string correctDestenation = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
while (correctDestenation != "y" || correctDestenation != "n")
{
    Console.WriteLine(
        "Oops! You must enter a 'y' for yes and a 'n' for no");
    correctDestenation = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
}
```

Comment: it should not be || you must use &&

Comment: Before suspecting the operator, suspect your own logic and code.

Comment: I think it's a rather bold to claim that the inequality operator `!=` doesn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your logic is incorrect.  You want to use && instead of ||.

```
while (correctDestenation != "y" && correctDestenation != "n")
```

or, you can use [De Morgan's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) and look at it the other way, which is equivalent:

```
while (!(correctDestenation == "y" || correctDestenation == "n"))
```

Answer (score 2):

That condition will always be satisfied, as a character will not be equal to 'y' or equal to 'n'. Use && instead of ||.

Answer (score 1):

How about you use the AND operator

```
    while (correctDestenation != "y" && correctDestenation != "n")
    {
           Console.WriteLine("Oops! You must enter a 'y' for yes and a 'n' for no");
           correctDestenation = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
    }
```